# How to show date using laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to show date (I'm using Laravel) like this

> Period: 11-06-2017 - 18-06-2017

using this code

```
<p class="panel-subtitle">Period: {{date("d-m-Y")-7}} - {{date("d-m-Y")}}</p>
```

but it showed like this

> Period: 11 - 18-06-2017

Is there any solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Carbon to format the date for you:

```
<p class="panel-subtitle">Period: {{ Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->format('d-m-Y') }} - {{ Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y') }}</p>
```